# Issues with a fixed header sometimes disappearing on iOS

Tags: ios, css

I'm working on [this site](http://dev.inprint.com.au/wordpress3) and am having some issues with a fixed header. Currently, when the viewport goes under 952px width the nav is moved to a bar at the top of the screen with position: fixed. Obviously this is to give mobile devices etc more screen space for content.

The issue is that on iOS7 (tested on iPhone and iPad), when using the dropdown nav to go to a new page, the nav disappears after the page loads and doesn't reappear until the user either scrolls down or changes device orientation. The issue doesn't come up on any web browser I've tested. I don't have any Android or other devices on hand at the moment to test on there.

I've tried looking online for an an answer or even a clue as to what's happening with no luck so far. Anyone have any idea what might be happening and (even better!) how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things which could possibly be causing this.

#### 1. Missing semicolon in your css media query for .tinynav display: block

```
@media (max-width: 952px) {
    .tinynav{
    display: block;
    }
}
```

#### 2. "@media only screen and"

When using media queries on a mobile device it is best practice to use this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 952px) {}
```

#### 3. Meta head tag

In the head of your html you need to include the following meta tag in order for mobile devices such as iPhones or iPads to detect media queries properly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you get it working as expected :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've made those changes and the issue is still occuring. It's a really strange issue!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.. it may have something to do with the fact that you are using a subdomain for your website? Sometimes when using subdomains they [cloak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) your website. What this does is put your whole webpage in an iFrame and from my experience ios devices don't deal with iFrames very well. Try visiting the root url of your hosting service and that might solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Chrome, it seems to be a bug that occurs when there is too much going on inside the page, I was able to fix it by adding the following transform code to the fixed position element, (`transform: translateZ(0);-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`) that forces the browser to use hardware acceleration to access the device’s graphical processing unit (GPU) to make pixels fly. Web applications, on the other hand, run in the context of the browser, which lets the software do most (if not all) of the rendering, resulting in less horsepower for transitions. But the Web has been catching up, and most browser vendors now provide graphical hardware acceleration by means of particular CSS rules.

Using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); will kick the GPU into action for the CSS transitions, making them smoother (higher FPS).

**Note:** translate3d(0,0,0) does nothing in terms of what you see. it moves the object by 0px in x,y and z axis. It's only a technique to force the hardware acceleration.

```
#element {
    position: fixed;
    /* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* seems to do the same in Safari Family of Browsers*/
}
```